# TypeError: url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name_space'

Tags: python, django, typeerror, django-urls

I know it looks like a simple problem but I'm still too new for sorting it out myself, so :

**learning_log/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', 'learning_logs.urls',name_space='learning_logs'),
        ]
```

Previously I had the following error so I've removed the include function

> ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

---

**learing_logs/urls.py**

```
"""Defines URL patterns for learning_logs."""

    from django.conf.urls import  url

    from . import views

    urlpatterns=[
        #Homepage
        url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),

    ]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

    #Create your views here.

    def index(request):
        """The home page for Learning Log"""
        return render(request,'learning_logs/index.html')
```

I'm using Django 2.0 and Python 3.6.1

Could you please advise why I'm getting TypeError with name_space arg, is that related to Django version, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `include()` to include urls patterns from another `urls.py`

```
url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls')),
```

There is no `name_space` argument with an underscore. The `include()` function accepts `namespace`. However, as the error message suggests, you should set `app_name` in the included `urls.py` instead of using `namespace`. You don’t need to use `namespace` unless you are including the same urls multiple times.

```
from . import views
app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns=[
    #Homepage
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),

]
```

Comment: Thank you @Alasdair your solution worked perfectly for me. Have a good evening !

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you want is likely `name` not `name_space`

```
url(r'', 'learning_logs.urls', name='learning_logs')
```

[(Django 2.0 `url()` Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#url)